# Haskell Maybe type -> type

Tags: haskell, option-type

I am running into this problem :

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Maybe Int’
```

Can I somehow convert ‘Maybe Int’ into ‘Int’??

```
if index == Nothing 
   then 
     do 
       let index = 0
       putStrLn(fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! index)
   else 
     do 
       let index = index
       putStrLn(fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! index)
```

I tried like this, but this gives me :

```
Exception: <<loop>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several different options to get around this

First is using your `if` statement, but with a small modification (Avoid doing this though)

```
if index == Nothing 
   then 
     do 
       let index' = 0
       putStrLn $ fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! index'
   else 
     do 
       let (Just index') = index
       putStrLn $ fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! index'
```

I'm writing `index'` here, because Haskell doesn't allow you to overwrite existing variables, it does however let you hide them. But generally it's better practice to label "modified" versions of a variable with a "prime" symbol (`'`) at the end. That way you can always access the original if need be.

Second you can use a `case` expression which turns your code into

```
case index of
  Just i  -> putStrLn $ fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! i
  Nothing -> putStrLn $ fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! 0
```

Or if you clean it up a bit using a `where` clause:

```
case index of
  Just i  -> putIndex i
  Nothing -> putIndex 0
where putIndex x = putStrLn $ fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! x
```

Lastly there's `fromMaybe` which lets you do this:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

-- ...

do
  let index' = fromMaybe 0 index
  putStrLn $ fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! index'
```

You can also use guards. But seeing as I don't know where your code-snippet comes from, I don't know if it's reasonable to use guards.

You can read more about guards, case expressions and pattern matching [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)

Comment: I would advice not to use `if`, unless it is quite necessary. Not that you do this in a *monadic* environment, which means that you enforce an order of computation, which is against the lazy programming principle of Haskell.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh I agree completely. I just wanted to demonstrate a few different ways to do this

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use the [`fromMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) function:

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
```

It works as follows, the first argument is the *default value*, something you use in case the second is `Nothing`, next follows the `Maybe a`, if that value is `Just x`, `x` is returned. So an implementation of `fromMaybe` could be:

```
fromMaybe _ (Just x) = x
fromMaybe d Nothing = d
```

So you could use:

```
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

--...

putStrLn(fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! (fromMaybe 0 index))
```

Without all the `if-then-else` wich is rather *un-Haskell*.

---

**Why** does it loop? Well in case that your `index` is of the form `Just x`, it goes into the following branch:

```
do 
   let index = index
   putStrLn(fancyPrint2 $ kaasasOlevList !! index)
```

Now the expression:

```
   let index = index
```

means that you assign `index` **to itself** (not the outer `index`). That's not really a problem in a functional programming language, although it becomes problematic if you want **to use such function**.